# Recommendation for a book on dynamic systems

Tags: reference-request

Could someone recommend an undergrad textbook on dynamical systems which covers the following topics:

1. transfer functions and frequency response
2. Analysis of block diagrams
3. Bode plot, Nyquist plot, central locus theorem
4. gain, phase margin?

I took a course in dynamic systems using the textbook by sontag, which is highly mathematical and contains no practical materials as mentioned above. http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/mct.html
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [Control Systems Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470547561) by Norman S. Nise deals with the theory of linear dynamical systems and their control. It contains all the topics you are mentioning. The mathematical level is very accessible and it contains tones of applications as well as many study cases on different practical systems which evolves chapter by chapter in parallel with the theory. I strongly recommend it. Sontag is mainly for those who are interested in classic mathematical control theory.

Comment: This book is very proper for my purpose. However it costs 140 pounds. Is there a cheaper alternative?

Comment: Maybe you could find some cheaper version in chinese (if you can speak chinese, of course)? I strongly think that you should not reduce the quality of your study by getting a cheaper book. This one is the best in my opinion for its purpose.

Comment: Well I guess I have to live with the fact that engineering books are expensive.

Comment: Also, check your university library.

Answer (score 2):

At my university we have used [Feedback Control of Dynamic Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136019692) by Gene F. Franklin. It covers all the topics you mentioted. I have really enjoyed this one.

Answer (score 1):

At last I decided to use [Feedback Systems: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/Main_Page) by Karl J. Åström and Richard M. Murray

This is an excellent book and contains all I need. The best thing is while most other similar books cost more than $100,  this one is free.

Answer (score 0):

The book [Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos: With Applications To Physics, Biology, Chemistry, And Engineering (Studies in Nonlinearity)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470547561) by Steven H. Strogatz has good applications

Comment: Thanks but I don't find what I really need in this book.