# Book on Complex Dynamic Systems Economics

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm searching for a good text book on economic Dynamics. I already read the book from Richard Day but I'm still struggling a little bit and I need some further material. I saw this post [Recommendation for a book on dynamic systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314202/recommendation-for-a-book-on-dynamic-systems) but I'm searching for something in the field of economics and I don't need any Proofs or sophisticated theorems.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend G. Gandolfo, \emph{Economic Dynamics}, 4th edition, 2009. See http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642038624